# Deleting a row in laravel via a button

Tags: php, sql, laravel

This question was asked a lot I know the posts that were posted helped me out a little bit and I have something like this right now.

Controller:

```
public function destroy($delete)
{
    $delete->delete();
    return redirect()->route('cd.index')->with('success','deleted successfully!');
}
```

And something like this in my view for the button on each row:

```
@foreach ($scores as $score)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $score->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $score->serialnumber }}</td>
    <td>{{ $score->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $score->created_at }}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete this Row</button>
        {{ csrf_field() }}
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is the result I and I dont get any errors, but the button does nothing:

[image: Rendered view]

Comment: Do you have a `<form>` somewhere?

Comment: I tried something like that: <form action="{{{ url('your url')}}}"> but it didnt helped me out

Comment: Add method('Delete') to your form to fire delete action.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be deleted instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="{{route('cd.index',$core->id)}}">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;Add New Record
                    </a>

public function destroy($delete){
  $data = YourModel::find($delete); 
  $data->delete(); or 

 YourModel::where('id',$delete)->first();
 $data->delete();

 return redirect()->route('cd.index')
                  ->with('success','deleted successfully!');
}
```

Comment: I dont need a form?

Comment: No, you do not need a form. The button should have the id you want to delete and just pass it to the route.

Comment: When i try it like this:   <a href="{{route('cd.index')}}"><button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete this Row</button></a> i get an error that the route is not defined. And it is defined in the web.php

Comment: `<button>` inside `<a>` is not allowed though: "_The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g., buttons or other links)._"

Comment: @Devi do u have your route {{route('cd.index')}} ?? its your routing problem

Comment: Web.php: Route::post('cd/index/{id}', 'cdController@destroy'); and then we have in the view: <form action="{{ url('cd/index/' . $score->id) }}" method="POST"> the route is not defined laravel says

Comment: i have updated the answer please check
Route::get('cd/index/{id}', 'cdController@destroy')->name('cd.index');
your route will be like this
{{route('cd.index',$core->id)}}

Comment: And he paste this in my URL: 127.0.0.1:8000/cd/index/22222222

Comment: still getting an error that says that the route is not defined

Comment: Route::get('cd/index/{id}', 'cdController@destroy')->name('cd.index'); 
write your route like this way. @Devi

Comment: Now i get this error Method App\Http\Controllers\cdController::delete does not exist. Thats damn frustrating...

Comment: in your cd controller method will be destroy not delete

Comment: it is called destroy

Comment: yes 
Route::get('cd/index/{id}', 'cdController@destroy')->name('cd.index');
in your route your method name is destroy

Comment: <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="{{route('cd.index',$core->id)}}">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;Add New Record
                    </a>
$core->id send ?? avalialble

Comment: Okay this is the next error: Call to a member function delete() on null when i get a another one after this i quit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171691/discussion-between-kuldeep-mishra-and-devi).

Answer (score 1):

Your deletion should look something like this:

```
DB::table($tableName)->where('id', $delete)->delete();
```

$delete - id of record
$tableName - name of table where your records are stored

action:

```
{{ url('record/delete/' . $score->id) }}
```

Web route:

```
Route::post(record/delete/{id}, 'ControllerName@destroy');
```

HTML:

```
<td>
    <form action="..." method="POST">
       {{ csrf_field() }}
       <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete this Row</button>

    </form>
</td>
```

This will also allow you to delete multiple elements if you click on them before page has reloaded

Controllers: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers

Function has to be inside controller (app\Http\Controllers)

Routes: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing

Add route to routes file (routes\web.php)

Comment: Im really gratefull you answerd but i am a newbie where do i have to put all these things?